# WCF Services Integration (ESB?)

Tags: c#, wcf, esb

I am currently working on small project to lern about Web Services in .NET, my problem is as follows.

I have Bank WebService that 'handles' transfer of money, and another one Offer Service, What I would like to do is to have Bank Service inform my Offer Service when some money transfer happens. One solution would be call Offer Service directly, but that's not really the best solution. I thought about UDDI but that's too much work I think. As I understand ESB could be used here, but frankly I have no idea how to use it. I mean how do I call offer service from bank service without direct call.

Maybe NServiceBus could be use here, but again no idea how to get it to work with WCF.
Any thoughts ?

Edit:
Ok to make it clearer, I would like to know, how could I user ESB, or other framework / service to decouple WebServices, so that one doesn't directly calls the other.

Comment: I feel this is just too broad of a question. Even the title says nothing. I'd say it needs some heavy rewording to fit as an actual question, and then you will see that what you are asking has been probably discussed numerous times, so it would probably be a duplicate.

Comment: I would tend to disagree with @oleksii on this - the way you have described the requirement in your question and subsequent comment leads me to think using messaging is the best approach. This is based on the assumption that the Bank service does not need the response from the Offer service in order to fulfill requests from callers, and that the services are sufficiently divergent from a business capability perspective that they need to be managed as separate concerns.

Answer (score 0):

> One solution would be call Offer Service directly, but that's not really the best solution.

Why? It is a good solution. Many systems work like that. I am not sure why you think messaging will magically solve this problem. In fact, messaging is just another *type* of communication.

You should use the same communication technology to call one service into another service. This reduces complexity. Less stuff to learn, fewer places for things to go wrong, and more importantly same communication API, when you use Bank WebService, Offer Service or both.

You may also need to use transaction or distributed transaction. Local transaction is much easier to implement and is preferred way to guard operations.`

Comment: I'm aware that many systems work like that, I just thought that further decoupling of them would be a good idea. Also I would like to do that for the sake of learning new things, because I'm really interested how ESB could be used for integration in this simple example.
Also messaging is indirect, you send an event notification, and then some designated handler does the work, Bank Service wouldn't need to know to whom send the notification.

Comment: @user1418979 You might want to mention the motivation to decouple the services in your post, it would be clearer. I think it's a good way to go if the system gets more complex.

Comment: @henginy I think the answer to "the motivation to decouple the services" is already in the OP's question when he/she says: "I mean how do I call offer service from bank service without direct call". From this we can probably assume that the services are sufficiently different from a business capability perspective to warrant some level of decoupling.

Comment: @TomRedfern I think this answer seems to miss that motivation even if it can be deduced/assumed. The OP already needed to clarify it with a comment and I suggested copying that information to the question;)